# SQL Replication : Is there a way to take the same effect of Snapshot Replication by using Merge Replication?

Tags: sql, replication

I'm searching for proper method for maintaining Clone DB.

Log Shipping seems to be a good choice, but It seems not suitable for my purpose because in Log Shipping, the Secondary DB is not writable.
So I'm considering using Replication as an alternative.

As I Understand, features of Snapshot Replication are:

1. One can modify subscriber DB.
2. Any modifications made on subscriber DB are gone away on next sync.

I hope to take these features, but Snapshot Replication will take much resource when applied to large size Databases.

Question : Is it possible to take the same effect using Merge Replication? i.e,

1. Modifications made on subscriber are not merged into Publisher.
2. Modifications made on subscriber are reverted on next sync.

( i'm using SQL Server 2005 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used merge replication for about 8 years, and we have a lot of customers that are using it for the intended use - multiple servers and both are in use. But we do have some that are using it for 100% backup purposes. I just setup merge replication just like i would for other machines and it replicates from the distributor to the subscriber. You can't make merge replication 100% one way, so your clone DB would be used only when needed (primary goes down), or for read-only access by an application.
If your clone DB is for backup purposes only, the way i understand is Microsoft doesn't require you to purpose another copy of SQL server and you can use the same license on both machines.
You can also setup the merge replication to either be continuously (which is how we have all of ours setup except for a couple), or you can set it up to only occur at certain times or a certain time interval. This is very helpful when the clone DB doesn't have to be 100% up to date all the time. So you could set it up to merge only at 10pm, and then all changes that occurred throughout the day will be replicated.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to make the clone DB writable for testing purpose. So the Snapshot replication seems to be appropriate for my case. Thanks.